# In Ableton Live, can a parameter be mapped to midi messages from a midi track?

Tags: midi, ableton-live

In Ableton Live, I'd like to use a midi track to toggle a parameter.

It seems like it should be possible to map a parameter to a midi note, say G2 on channel 1, and then have that map triggered from a midi track.

I'm thinking that something like [Jack OS X](http://www.jackosx.com) could be set up to control Ableton, and then midi could be routed out of the midi track and though Jack, but I think there should be a simpler way.

Comment: I think this video from Ableton's Dennis DeSantis should get you started. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YS-e2r5bef0

Comment: @Phrancis That video doesn't answer the question. The question is about internal MIDI tracks controlling Live as a control surface would.

Comment: Are you using Ableton 9? Ableton 9 has more possibilities with controlling parameters. Also, what parameters are you trying to control?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you need to implement MIDI loopback to achieve this, virtually (like as you mentioned, with Jack OSX) or with physical MIDI ports.

*But* there is a chance that this is something you can do with a Max for Live device. You might be able to build the device yourself, or maybe someone already did it and you just need to find it.

That might be an overkill for automation though. Is there a specific reason you need to implement your automation that way? The native automation tools seem to be much more flexible and powerful than a MIDI loopback.